# Laravel 5.6 populate field after submit

Tags: php, forms, laravel-5, laravelcollective

I use the Laravel Collective system to build my forms and I am trying to populate my formfields with the values that were submitted after the page reloads like this:

```
{{ Form::text('id', {{ request('id') }} , array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

This throws this error:

> syntax error, unexpected '{'

Comment: why you are using a {{}} around request ? try this : `{{ Form::text('id',  request('id')  , array('class' => 'form-control')) }}`

Comment: @Zoha I tried that, doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: the error that you have is for that I said, everything in double brackets is considered as a php syntax and { is not a PHP valid syntax

Comment: you can use `old()` method I think

Answer (score 0):

`old('id')` Should return the input named `id` from last request.

So in your case:

`{{ Form::text('id', old('id') , array('class' => 'form-control')) }}`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using blade inside blade:

```
\/                  \/
{{ Form::text('id', {{ request('id') }} , array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

And this is not accepted obviously.

You must keep in mind that once you open a blade tag `{{`, the blade will translate it to this:

```
<?php echo Form::text('id', {{ request('id') }} , array('class' => 'form-control')) ?>
```

Note that it doesn't work recursively, so the second level blade tag will not be translated, and `{` is a invalid character inside a PHP code.

To solve it, you shouldn't (and needn't) use the second level blade tag:

```
{{ Form::text('id', request('id'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

Of course, I'm assuming that the `request()` function exists, otherwise it will throw an error: `Call to undefined function request()`.

---

To solve your problem (not the error), you should use the `old()` method instead of `request()`, since it uses the value stored by Laravel on session.

Note that this approach works in two situations:

- When a validation error occurs.
- When you have flashed the fields manually.

This behaviors are described [here on Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#old-input)

Comment: Yes, that is the error. But not what he asked to be honest.

Comment: The question itself is confusing, he starts asking something, then show a piece of code that don't work throwing that error. I explained how to fix that error, but if the logic don't work, that's another problem.

Comment: Title is self-explanatory, but it's true that the question remains vague.